# How can I tell if a website is firing virtual page views?

Tags: google-analytics, http-headers

Is there a way to know how many page views are being fired, including virtual pageviews, when a browser lands on a page?

I'm investigating a severe bounce rate drop that is pretty clearly a technical issue since there has been no content or layout changes on the site.

We do have:
2 Google Analytics tags (Classic and Universal) throughout the site;
Optimizley is set up and testing.

Could this cause the problem?

Note, there is currently no event tracking on the site, just the base analytics tags.

Is there a way to see what tags (assuming that's it) are causing the issue? I am using httpfox (like fiddler) and added filter "utm" to see what's going on. Sure enough, 2 GA tags firing plus 2 dart pixels.

Would those cause page views though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check what is firing on the entire page. Download firbug for firefox and add the "omnibug" extension. The omnibug extension should be in the firefox firebug window when you open it.

When you go the omnibug in the firefix panel, you will see EVERYTHING THAT IS FIRING!

Is that what you are looking for?

---

To check what pageviews are firing correctly VERY QUICKLY in Google analytics. Do the following;

1. Make sure the google analytics code you have is on the page you want to track
2. Make sure your IP is not excluded or filtered out of the analytics profile
3. Login to your google analytics account
4. Go to **Real-Time** section on the left hand sidebar.
5. Click on **Content**
6. Go to your site and click on the link or go to the virtual pageview page you added the code to and then watch if that link shows up in the **real-time -> content** section.

Comment: Omnibug - useful too that I've added to my browser. There's 7 tags firing ont he site in question though: Google-Tag-Manager; Google Analytics (Classic), Google Universal Analytics and Optimizley. The type in each case says analytics, except optimizley says event. Wonder if it's an event causing a virtual page view.

Comment: If your GA tags send to different properties (which they should do since they are for different versions of ga) that should not be a problem (but you should still check the request to see if the UA id is different). If an event affects the bounce rate you should see it in the events section of the behaviour reports, so that's easy to check.